# Passive clauses of reason replaced by " being + past participle" structure

Tags: grammar

"Because the door was jammed, I couldn't get in"=
"The door being jammed, I couldn't get in".

I would like to ask, what kind of structure "The door being jammed" is and what is the grammar rule that indicates that the latter structure can replace the clause of reason. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [absolute construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction). The only essentials are a noun phrase that is not the subject of the main clause, and a participle: usually a present rather than a past participle, and generally of a stative rather than an active verb.

Most often the participle is either "being", or "having" followed by a past participle; but other verbs are possible.